Maximizing the number of colors so that every subgrid contains all colors
Consider an $n\times n$ grid. Define the set $S$ as subgrids shapes which includes all $(i,j)$ pairs so that $i\times j=n$. eg: we can take $i=1, j=n$ which is a row shape structure and it belongs to the set. we can also take $i=2, j=\frac{n}{2}$ as long as $2|n$. Define cells as the $1\times 1$ small square in the grid. eg: $i=1, j=n$ has $n$ cells. Define a valid coloring as a function maps the cells to a set of colors $K$ so that it has the following property: For every subgrid in $n*n$ grid which has the shape in the set $S$, it contains all colors in $K$.
If we choose $n=6$ , all subgrids shapes are $1*6, 2*3, 3*2, 6*1$. Then we consider all the subgrids in $6*6$ which has the shape $1*6, 2*3, 3*2, 6*1$. So, it will be 6 columns, 6 rows, probably 20 $2*3$ subgrids and 20 $3*2$ subgrid.
What is the maximum size of $K$?
My thinking:
$K$ should definitely less or equal to $n$, otherwise the statement will not hold. If we consider $n=4$,the maximum number of colors is actually 3 by bruteforce search. I feel like the result for general $n$ which is not a prime should be around $\frac{n}{2}$ but could not prove it.

1/ Can you include your proof of $n=4$, or at least shed some color on how you approached the search? 2/ To clarify, does the subgrid need to consist of consecutive rows and columns?

Sure. If $|K|=4$ when n=4, the coloring must be a latin square, so I just check all 4 by 4 latin squares. Here is a website http://finitegeometry.org/sc/16/latin4x4.html.

The subgrids need to be consecutive rows and columns, If we choose n=6 , all subgrids shapes are 16, 23, 32, 61. Then we consider all the subgrids in 66 which has the shape 16, 23, 32, 61.. So, it will be 6 columns, 6 rows, probably 20 23 subgrids and 20 3*2 subgrids.

1/ FYI Note that there are actually 576 $4 \times 4$ Latin squares, so your brute force approach would have to search through all of them (not just those in the site that you linked. Usually people don't display the permutations of rows + columns + numbers. EG Set the first row and column to both be $1, 2, 3, 4$, but then that will invalidate the top left $ 2 \times 2 $ sub grid. $\quad$ A much quicker and simpler approach is to show that if the first row is 1, 2, 3, 4, and the second row first cell is 2, (or 3, or 4), then we won't be able to continue.$\quad$2/ I encourage you to add that in.

As a counterpoint to "for general $n$, $K$ should be around n/2": For prime $n$, we have $K = n$. Just label the cell $(i, j) $ with $ i + j \pmod{n}$. Since the sub grids are just $ 1 \times n, n \times 1$, the result follows. $\quad$ For composite $n$, you can easily show that $ K < n$ (like with $n = 4$ case).

Yes, you are right for prime n. The composite is the most difficult part.

I get $K(6) = 5$, and I believe that $K(9) = 7$ (but can't prove that 8 is impossible).

Did you have some "elegant" pattern when you try to construct? I feel like starting is kinda easy and elegant, but will meet strict restrction soon and then the construction is just trying to fulfilll all restrctions.

I modified the $i+j \pmod{K}$ approach and used $ i + 2 j \pmod {K}$, then tweaked it a bit to make it work. The idea is to make the overlap occur in the first and last row (or column), which makes sense as you think about shifting the sub grid row by row (and column by column). $\quad$ Wasn't immediately clear to me how to generalize, and I stopped investigating further.
